# Set PYTHONPATH in MWAA

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm trying to use local module inside a dag on MWAA.

The folder structure looks like :

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_dag
│      ├── __init__.py
│      └── dag.py
│   └── utils
│      ├── __init__.py
│      └── file.py
│      └── secrets.py
│      └── date.py
```

I try to use functions from `./dags/utils/secrets` by importing them like :

```
from dags.utils.secrets import get_secret
```

Locally, I've been able to make it works by setting environment variable PYTHONPATH to `usr/local/airflow`

Is it the best way ? If not how can I make it works on MWAA ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Locally, I've been able to make it works by setting environment variable PYTHONPATH to usr/local/airflow
>
> Is it the best way ? If not how can I make it works on MWAA ?

When deploying Airflow to an MWAA environment, you don't explicitly set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

> I try to use functions from ./dags/utils/secrets by importing them like :
>
> from dags.utils.secrets import get_secret

Adjust the Python `import` statement relative to the MWAA environment's DAGs folder. For example, if the DAGs folder is `s3://<bucket>/dags`, then the import statement would be:

```
from utils.secrets import get_secret
```

Example DAGs folder:

```
s3://<bucket>/dags/__init__.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/my_dag/__init__.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/my_dag/dag.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/utils/__init__.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/utils/file.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/utils/secrets.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/utils/date.py
```

Comment: The adjustment seems to work perfectly, thank you !

Comment: No problem @Sébastien! Feel free to accept the answer if the solution is correct.

Comment: This adjustment obviously works, but it goes against good practices not having the full path in your package imports (and IDEs will complain). Any other idea around?

Comment: I have the same issue, and I have some utils module outside the dags folder from which I make imports, but it doesn't work on MWAA. how can I adjust the absolute path on the cloud please?

Comment: There's an issue with this solution. It can't resort imports from the same level. E.g. if there is two sub-modules: `dag/utility/utils.py` and `dag/includes/my_module.py`, the `from utility.utils import *` won't work. MWAA either throws a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility'` exception or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dags'` dependendent on relative or absolute imports used. 

IMHO MWAA is the worst Airflow service out there.