# MWAA/Airflow: Importing task code into dag files from submodules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I'm using MWAA on AWS for a workflow orchestration project. I have a DAG folder structure like this (and gets uploaded into S3 like this, with the MWAA Dags folder set to `src/dags`):

```
src/
├─ dags/
│  ├─ first_dag/
│  │  ├─ tasks/
│  │  │  ├─ task_01/
│  │  │  │  ├─ task.py
│  │  │  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  │  ├─ task_02/
│  │  │  │  ├─ task.py
│  │  │  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ dag.py
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
```

`src/dags/first_dag/dag.py` looks something like this:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from first_dag.tasks.task_01.task import create_task as create_task_01
from first_dag.tasks.task_02.task import create_task as create_task_02

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Me'
}

with DAG(dag_id='test', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args) as dag:
    task_01 = create_task_01()
    task_02 = create_task_02()

    task_01 >> task_02
```

and `src/dags/first_dag/tasks/task_01/task.py` and `src/dags/first_dag/tasks/task_02/task.py` are basically the same file like this:

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


def create_task():
    task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='dummy_task'
    )
    return task
```

My understanding from the [official Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html) is that the DAGs folder is automatically added to the `PYTHONPATH` env variable. Yet, the MWAA UI shows a DAG import error:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/first_dag/dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/first_dag/dag.py", line 2, in <module>
    from first_dag.tasks.task_01.task import create_task as create_task_01
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'first_dag.tasks'
```

I'm not really understanding why Python can't find the module - does MWAA do something different with `PYTHONPATH`? Am I importing incorrectly? How can I resolve?

Edit: I also tried adding the `first_dag` directory to a `plugins.zip` archive (removing the `dag.py` file) to see if it would recognize it as a plugin - still giving the `ModuleNotFound` error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar Stack Overflow question: [Set PYTHONPATH in MWAA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312432/set-pythonpath-in-mwaa)

> does MWAA do something different with PYTHONPATH?

No, it doesn't. However, it's never explicitly set by the user.

> Am I importing incorrectly? How can I resolve?

`dag.py` is in the `first_dag` sub-package, so it can be excluded from the `import` statement.

```py
from tasks.task_01.task import create_task as create_task_01
from tasks.task_02.task import create_task as create_task_02
```

This is explained more in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), which is also directly referenced in the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#don-t-use-relative-imports).